# Show that there is a neighborhood around 0 such that f(x)>0 .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f:[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function in the interval $(0,1)$ and $f(1)>0$. I'm wondering if there always exists some $\delta \in (0,1)$ such that for every $x \in (\delta, 1): f(x) > 0$.

What I have managed to do so far is the following:

Since $f$ is continuous for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in (\delta,1)$ we have $|f(x)-f(1)| < \epsilon$.

We assume that for every $\epsilon,\delta > 0$ there exists some $x_0 \in (\delta,1)$ such that  $f(x_0) < 0$. We have that

$$ |f(x_0)-f(1)|<\epsilon $$
$$ f(x_0)-f(1)>\epsilon $$
$$ f(x_0) > \epsilon + f(1) > 0$$
$$ f(x_0) > 0$$

(because $f(x_0) < 0 \implies f(x_0) - f(1) < 0$).

But we arrive at a contradiction because we assumed that $f(x_0) < 0$.
Therefore

$$\exists \; \epsilon_0,\delta_0 > 0 : \forall x \in (\delta_0,1), f(x)>0.$$

I'm wondering if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x=1\\ 0, & x\in [0,1)\end{cases}$?

Comment: If you give up continuity at $x=1,$ there is no relation between the values at $x<1$ and at $x=1.$

Comment: @Jose27 this function isn't continuous

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes, but if $f$ is continuous in the interval $(0,1]$ does it hold?

Comment: Yes, in that case if $x$ is close to $1$ then $f(x)$ is close to $f(1).$

Comment: No, your logic is messed up when you tried to proceed by contradiction. I would suggest a direct argument, but you need to choose $\epsilon$ appropriately.

Comment: @TedShifrin what do you think of the following argument? If I choose $\epsilon < f(1)$ there are 2 possibilities. Either $f(x) > f(1)$ witch implies that $f(x) > 0$ (since $f(1)>0$) or $f(x)<f(1)$ witch implies that $f(x) > 2 f(1) > 0$. Therefore for every $\epsilon > f(1)$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in (\delta,1)$ we have that $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Perfect except for the (important) typo!